# batch script for adb connect over wifi

Tags: batch-file, adb

i am trying to write a batch script to automate some task and ecocide next command or output according to the response or output from previous command.

```
adb connect %IP%:5555
 if errorlevel 1 (
      echo Not Able To connect With Provided Ip Address
      goto getip
) else (
    echo Connected Over Wifi
    goto menu2
    )
```

But it's not working because i think in every case error level is 0 
as device connected successfully or not output is same "Connected Over wifi".

Generaly when we enter command `adb connect <IP>` the outputs are

1)connection is successful output is

```
connected to 192.168.10.13:5555
```

2) when android device is in wifi lan and enterd "ip" is correct but "5555" port is not open then output is

```
unable to connect to 192.168.10.13:5555: cannot connect to 192.168.10.13:5555: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (10061)
```

3)when laptops wifi is off

```
unable to connect to 192.168.10.13:5555: cannot connect to 192.168.10.13:5555: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host. (10065)
```

4) when android's wifi is off

```
unable to connect to 192.168.10.2:5555: cannot connect to 192.168.10.2:5555: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060)
```

i want to define only two case `"connection Successful" or "Not Successful"`

what should i do to automate task according to the adb over wifi connection setup. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pipe the output of adb to FIND and search for a telltale token that indicates success or failure, like "unable to" or "connected to".

```
@echo off & setlocal
set IP=192.168.10.13:5555
adb connect %IP% | find /i "connected to" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Not successful
) else (
    echo Successful
)
```

Comment: Is it possible to pipe output once and use it again and again for searching tokens to decide what is the actual error then displaying that error

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Please check this link to my new questions, code derived from your answer I really need help please  http://stackoverflow.com/q/39988332/6885663