# batch script for adb over wifi

Tags: android, batch-file, adb

I have written a script for adb wireless connection with a nested if else but and i don't know what is the problem code it not executing properly
for every input there is same output 
does batch supports "nested if else " or not if yes then then please tell me 
what i am doing wrong. is there any syntax error.
please help me

```
@echo off
:getip
set ip=""
set /p ip=[-]  Please Enter IP Address :
echo.
if %ip%=="" echo      Please Enter Correct Ip & pause >nul & cls & goto getip
goto wireless
:wireless
setlocal
adb kill-server
::connected
adb connect %IP%:5555 | find /i "connected to" >nul
    if errorlevel 1 (

         ::laptop wifi off 
         adb connect %IP%:5555 | find /i "unreachable host" >nul
             if errorlevel 1 (

                :: Wrong Ip format
                adb connect %IP%:5555 | find /i "no such host" >nul
                    if errorlevel 1 (

                        ::5555 port off
                        adb connect %IP%:5555 | find /i "refused it" >nul
                            if errorlevel 1 (

                                :: Android Wifi Off
                                adb connect %IP%:5555 | find /i "faild to respond" >nul
                                    if errorlevel 1 (
                                        echo.
                                        echo   Unknown Error & pause >nul & goto getip
                                     )
                                    else(
                                         echo. & echo  Could Not connect To Given IP
                                         echo. & echo  Reason Can Be...
                                         echo. & echo  Android Is Not connected To Local Wifi
                                         echo. & echo  Or No Device With This Ip In LAN & echo >nul & goto getip
                                         )

                              )
                            else(
                                echo. & echo Android Wireless Port Is Off
                                echo. & echo Press Any Key To Turn On & pause >nul & goto adbport
                                )

                      )
                    else(
                        echo. & echo  Wrong Format IP Address...
                        echo. & echo  Please Enter IP In Given Format Example "192.168.10.10"
                        echo. & echo  Press Any Key To Continue.... & goto getip
                        )

               )
             else(
                 echo. & echo laptop/Desktop Wifi IS Off Or Not connected To Local Wifi/LAN
                 echo. & echo connect laptop/Desktop To The LAN. & echo. & echo pause >nul
                 echo Press Any Key To Go Back & goto getip
                 )
      )      
    else(
        cls
        echo. & echo        Android Hacker Is connected With The Victim's Device Wirelessly.
        echo        Now You Can Remove The USB & echo.
        echo        Press Any Key To Continue To Menu 2 & pause >nul & goto menu2
    )  


[-]  Please Enter IP Address :192.168.10.4

'else' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

 Wrong Format IP Address...

 Please Enter IP In Given Format Example "192.168.10.10"

 Press Any Key To Continue....
[-]  Please Enter IP Address :
```

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/pedrovgs/AndroidWiFiADB probably you'll find some useful infirmation there

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['else' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365374/else-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Comment: What about reading the help of `if` (type `if /?` into a command prompt window)? it clearly says how to buils an `if`/`else` block: `if <condition> (` _<br>_ `<command(s)>` _<br>_ `) else (` _<br>_ `<command(s)>` _<br>_ `)` (so there are spaces in between `)` and `else`, and there are no arbitrary line-breaks; the _<br>_ represents a line-break)...

Comment: Thanks for your help guys I'll try that.

Comment: To simplify, instead of piping your ADB Connect output to `find`, you can pipe it to a temporary file. Then run `find` on that temporary file. Also, it looks to me like your nested `if`s are mutually exclusive, that is, one occurs without another having to occur. In that case, you don't want to nest your ifs.

Comment: Actual I want to display comment according to the output so I need to check all the 5 cases to show the actual cause of failure

Comment: "adb connect" output can have any one of the five tokens 1.connected 2.unreachable 3.no such host 4.refused 5.faild to respond and I have to display different message respectively. So I need to check all the five tokens